# Не запускается видео на джанго

Tags: python, django, видео

Видео, которое добавил на сайт через django нельзя запустить

[image: ...]

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% for event in event_list %}
<div>
    <img src={{ event.evemntpic.url }}>
    {% for video in event.File.all %}
        <video><source src={{ video.video.url }} type="video/mp4"></video>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator


class Event(models.Model):
    eventname = models.CharField('Название мероприятия', max_length=100, default="")
    eventstartday = models.DateTimeField('Начало мероприятия', default=datetime.now())
    eventendday = models.DateTimeField('Конец мероприятия', default=datetime.now())
    eventdescription = models.CharField('Описание мероприятия', max_length=500, default="")
    ticketprice = models.IntegerField('Цена билета', default=0)
    eventminage = models.IntegerField('Минимальный возраст для посещения', default=0)
    evemntpic = models.ImageField('Промо-фото', upload_to='imgs/events/', default=0)

    hostname = models.SlugField('Организатор', max_length=100, default="", allow_unicode=1)
    hostemail = models.EmailField('Почта организатора', max_length=100, default="")
    hosttg = models.CharField('Телеграм', max_length=100, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.eventname


class ProductVideo(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='video/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4'])])
    product = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='File')
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from itertools import chain
from .models import *


def get_list_event(request):
    return render(request, 'html/index.html', {'event_list': Event.objects.all(),})
```

Comment: поставить controls preload="auto"